# How to place cursor on the canvas?

Tags: android

I have a android application which drawing text on the canvas.I have to write text the position where user touch on the canvas with a blinking cursor.

Comment: By the way, welcome to StackOverflow! You should probably know about the "Accept Answer" feature which allows you to mark people's answers as "Accepted". This helps people looking at your question later to determine if the answer actually worked for you - and gives the answerer some points (which are always appreciated!) You can mark an answer as accepted by clicking the green checkmark under the up/down voting buttons. You might want to do this for your other questions as well. Thanks! Have fun!